# How do I execute a "CONTINUE" statement inside a ".EACH" function of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please refer to comment inside the code below:

```
$('#btnDelete').on('click', function()
{
    var treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    var userId = $('#user_id').val();

    $('#treeview').find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function()
    {
        debugger;

        var li = $(this).closest(".k-item")[0];
        var notificationId = treeView.dataSource.getByUid(li.getAttribute('data-uid')).ID;

        if (notificationId == undefined)
        {
              //if the notification ID is "undefined" here, I want the ".EACH" 'loop' to continue to the next item.
        }
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '../api/notifications/deleteNotification?userId=' + userId + '&notificationId=' + notificationId,
                type: 'DELETE'
            }).done(function()
            {
                var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
                treeview.destroy();
                CreateNotificationTree(userId);
                console.log('Delete successful.');
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, status, error)
            {
                console.log("Error : " + error);
            });
        treeView.remove($(this).closest('.k-item'));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `return`:

```
if (typeof notificationId == "undefined")
{
    // exit the current function
    return;
}
```

This has the effect of going on to the next iteration, because `each` simply invokes the anonymous function for each iteration.

Comment: Note that you can return anything except `false` to continue the each loop.

Comment: thanks, this did the trick. I can accept your answer in 3 mins.

Answer (score 0):

```
return false;
```

really simple, works the same as `break` in traditional loops

edit: sorry, you need continue, not break. Sorry.